# Mypy type checker and "static instances"

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

For a class `A` I wrote, there are some instances `foo` and `bar` that I want to be accessible through `A.foo` and `A.bar` as class variables. However, `foo` and `bar` are both instances of `A`, and I'm not sure how to let the typechecker `mypy` handle this correctly. I currently instantiate `foo` and `bar` as follows:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  foo = None
  bar = None

A.foo = A()
A.bar = A()
```

Which leads `mypy` to conclude that `A.foo` and `A.bar` are of type `None`. Annotating as `Optional[A]` would work, but that's misrepresenting what is intended: I want both to be of type `A`... Any tips?

Comment: Why don't you just annotate it as `foo: A`? Why are you even setting it to `None` to begin with?

Comment: Because I can't instantiate instances of class A before the class definition has finished.

Comment: You **don't need to**. Just annotate the variable with `A` and instantiate it outside, like you just did. If you assign `None` then you *have* to use `Optional`

Comment: Huh. I just tried it before your comment, no idea that this was possible, TIL.

Comment: Note, you will have to use `from __future__ import annotations` if you want to be able to use `A` instead of `"A"`, unless you are already on Python 3.10 (where this will become the default behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using a higher version of python 3, you can use annotations to do this for you.

```
foo : A
```

I think mypy works with standard annotations. If this doesn't work, then try surrounding the annotation with quotes.

```
foo : "A"
```

Comment: **Don't assign `None`**. That is incorrect. If you are going to use `None`, then it should be `Optional[A]`. Just use `foo: A` (using `from __future__ import annotations` if you need to be able to refer to an annotation before the variable is defined)

Comment: That's right. I forgot about that. Thanks